# Getting parentheses around standard errors when using -esttab-

Tags: latex, stata

I am producing summary statistics tables by using `estpost` and `esttab`,
however, even by specifying the `parentheses` option, I am not able to get the parentheses around the standard errors.

The code I am using is equivalent to the following:

```
clear all
sysuse auto, clear

qui eststo: estpost tabstat weight price, by(foreign) ///
    statistics(mean sd) columns(statistics) listwise nototal

esttab using "outcomes.tex", replace booktabs ///
    main(mean) aux(sd) unstack nostar noobs nonote nomtitle nonumber ///
    title("Summary Statistics") ///
    cells("mean" "sd") gaps compress par ///
    collabels(none)
```

The resulting `outcomes.tex` can be compiled in Latex by using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \input{outcomes.tex}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
The same problem happens if I try to put standard errors in brackets by using the `br` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example:

```
clear all
sysuse auto, clear

eststo: estpost tabstat weight price, by(foreign) ///
    statistics(mean sd) columns(statistics) listwise nototal

// yours
esttab, main(mean) aux(sd) unstack nostar noobs nonote nomtitle nonumber ///
    title("Summary Statistics") ///
    cells("mean" "sd") gaps compress par ///
    collabels(none)

// proposed
esttab, unstack nostar noobs nonote nomtitle nonumber ///
    title("Summary Statistics") ///
    cells(mean sd(par)) gaps compress par ///
    collabels(none)
```

Remember to go over `help estout`, as `esttab` is just a wrapper for the former.